# Cloneable in Derived Classes

Tags: c#, icloneable

Assume I have a class `A`, and `B` which derives from `A`:

```
class A : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone() {...}
}

class B : A, ICloneable
{
    public object Clone() {...}
}
```

which gives

```
'B.Clone()' hides inherited member 'A.Clone()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

warning.

(1) What is the suggested way? using `new` or declaring `A.Clone()` as `virtual` and `override` in `B`?

(2) If there are some members in `A` and properly cloned in `A.Clone()`, is there an easy way to clone them in `B.Clone()` or do I have to explicitly clone them in `B.Clone()` also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have access to your source (which I'm guessing is the case here) then absolutely declare it as `virtual` and override it. If hide the base `Clone` with `new` might be a bad idea. If any code doesn't *know* that it's working with a `B`, then it will fire the *wrong* clone method and not return a proper clone.

Regarding the assignment of properties, perhaps consider implementing copy constructors and each level can handle its own cloning:

```
    public class A : ICloneable
    {
        public int PropertyA { get; private set; }

        public A()
        {

        }

        protected A(A copy)
        {
            this.PropertyA = copy.PropertyA;
        }

        public virtual object Clone()
        {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }

    public class B : A, ICloneable
    {
        public int PropertyB { get; private set; }

        public B()
        {

        }

        protected B(B copy)
            : base(copy)
        {
            this.PropertyB = this.PropertyB;
        }

        public override object Clone()
        {
            return new B(this);
        }
    }
```

Each copy constructor calls the base copy constructor passing itself down the chain. Each inheritance level copies the properties belonging to it directly.

EDIT: If you use the `new` keyword to hide the base implementation, here's an example of what might happen. With a sample implementation (which on the face of it looks fine)

```
public class A : ICloneable
{
    public int PropertyA { get; protected set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clone A called");
        A copy = new A();
        copy.PropertyA = this.PropertyA;
        return copy;
    }
}

public class B : A, ICloneable
{
    public int PropertyB { get; protected set; }

    public new object Clone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clone B called");
        B copy = new B();
        copy.PropertyA = this.PropertyA;
        copy.PropertyB = this.PropertyB;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

But when you use it:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
B bCopy = (B)a.Clone();
//"Clone A called" Throws InvalidCastException! We have an A!
```